# Android - popup window or something else

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am currently developing an android app that displays a list view. When an item from the list view is selected I would like a small window to appear from the bottom of the screen. This window will not cover the entire list view, but take up a small portion of the bottom. On this window will be a few buttons and a progress bar.

My question is would the best way to achieve this be through a popupwindow or is there something else to better suit this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) with a custom View ([Android Custom Dialog example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)). Or you can forgo the concept of the pop-up and just "fake it" by adding your "pop-up" View into your normal layout but setting it as invisible. Then when you want to show it make it Visible and populate it with the appropriate data.

Comment: My concern with a Dialog is that it takes away focus from my list view. I want the user to be able to interact with both the window at the bottom as well as the listview while both are present.

Comment: then I suggest the second option in my answer. Put your pop-up layout inside your regular layout and use visibility to hide/show it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a really good direction. Mad props on being the first to claim "Tim" as a username on Stack Overflow btw.

Comment: whoops that tutorial link was totally meant for a different question =x. Also the Usernames aren't unique so there are many other Tim's on here, I doubt I was anywhere near the first.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit in the dark on the tutorial :). If you find something applicable please feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you meant. Do you use ActionBarSherkock? If yes, then there is a splitactionbar which is ususally located on the bottom of the screen, when the screen is small. It looks like this:
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/actionbar_menu_sherlock_splitactionbar.png

Is this what you meant? Let me please know.

Edit:
There is something called quick actions. This handels popups very well, but its not displayed on the bottom of the screen tough. But you might want to look at it:
http://londatiga.net/images/quickactions/quickcontact.jpg

Comment: The quick action appears next to the item displayed. I would prefer it to anchor to the bottom of the screen to keep the interface clean. The split action bar may work if it can be customized to include both a progress bar and a text view.

Comment: I think the split actionbar can be customized. But I have  to look it up